# php myslql select from multiple table

Tags: php, mysql, select

i have multiple drop list box that contain data from the database so i want to select the second drop list based on the section of the first one
the first table have these three fields 
**district_id(primary key),district_name, governorate_id(foreign key)**
second table has these three fields 
**village_id(primary key), village_name, district_id(foreign key)**

so i want the user to select the district box first then based on the select district name that have an id i want that the second box display all the village name that have a village.district_id = district.district_id.
can anyone help me??
i was selecting each table independent from the other one but i need it to be based on the first one

## chunk of the code

```
function districtQuery(){

$distData = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM districts");

  while($recorddist = mysql_fetch_array($distData)){

     echo'<option value="' . $recorddist['district_name'] .  '">' . $recorddist['district_name'] . '</option>';

  }


}
// function for select by village
function villageQuery(){

//$villageData = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM village");

  $villageData = mysql_query("SELECT village_name FROM village WHERE district_id = ('SELECT district_id FROM districts')") or die (mysql_error());

  while($recordvillage = mysql_fetch_array($villageData)){

     echo'<option value="' . $recordvillage['village_name'] .  '">' . $recordvillage['village_name'] . '</option>';

  }


}
```

**ps**  i do not know how to use ajax and jquery

Comment: Don't use the mysql_query specific syntax, It's deprecated. Use mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple problems in your `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE district_id = ('SELECT district_id FROM districts')
```

First, remove the single quote from the inner select:

```
WHERE district_id = (SELECT district_id FROM districts)
```

Next, note that this will fail if the subquery (`SELECT district_id FROM districts`) returns more than one row. I suspect you want something like this:

```
WHERE district_id IN (SELECT district_id from districts)
```

Finally, your query just gets a list of every village that has a defined district_id. The recommended way to do that is with an `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT village_name
FROM village
INNER JOIN districts ON village.district_id = districts.district_id
```

---

**Addendum**: full query based on feedback.

I can't help with the PHP/Ajax, but I know that it'll deliver the district ID for you if everything is hooked up properly. When you get it, just use this basic query:

```
SELECT village_name FROM village WHERE district_id = <your district id value>
```

Good, luck, and sorry I can't help with the Ajax part.

Comment: this query did not work for me but that is exactly what i want your query is the selected one but **ps** SELECT district_id FROM districts return a list of districts name

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by "ps SELECT district_id FROM districts". Could you describe a little more what results you want to get? I'm sure I or any of the other folks here could help.

Comment: ok  i have a district table that have 3 fields district name  and district id (is the primary key/ foreign key in the village table) village table have village name and village id.... so i want to make the user select first the district list then in the village list i want to display only the villages that have the same district id in the district table.

Comment: Got it. I've posted an update to my answer but unfortunately it only addresses the query. I don't know PHP/Ajax so I'm afraid I can't help there.